# Delete all records apart from latest

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which contains a field for CreatedOn.

How would I delete all records except for the newest 1 million records (newest being based on CreatedOn)

Thanks

Comment: Great, what's stopping you?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways of accomplishing this. Try the following query which is self explanatory:

```
DELETE FROM tableName where PrimaryKeyColumn NOT IN (SELECT TOP 1000000 PrimaryKeyColumn FROM tableName ORDER BY CreatedOn DESC)
```

Comment: If `CreatedOn` is not unique, you might think about `TOP ... WITH TIES`. Otherwise this could lead to a (probably not important) random behvaiour... +1 from my side

Comment: @ben, if you found this answer helpful, please mark is as an answer and upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

With something like

```
SELECT TOP 1 y.CreatedOn FROM (SELECT TOP 1000000 x.CreatedOn 
                               FROM MyTable AS x 
                               ORDER By x.CreatedOn DESC) AS y
ORDER BY y.CreatedOn ASC
```

You'll get the `CreatedOn` date of your millionth record.

Now delete all having a `CreatedOn` smaller than this

Answer (score 0):

```
With cteOrdered AS
(
Select ID, CreatedOn, Row_Number() Over (Order By CreatedOn Desc) SortOrder
    From Table_1
)
Delete T1
    From Table_1 T1
    Join cteOrdered O On O.ID = T1.ID
    Where SortOrder > 4
```

If you add another field in the row_number after CreatedOn Desc you can have more control over what to do with ties.